# Converting a python dictionary to cpp object

Tags: python, c++, dictionary

I have to convert a python object to c++ but I have no idea about python. The object looks like this:

```
VDIG = {
    1024 : [1,2,3,4],
    2048 : [5,6,7,8]
}
```

From the look of it I think it might be a map of lists?

What is the closes object that can be used in c++ ?

I tried to do like this but it does not compile:

```
std::map<int, std::list<int>> G_Calib_VoltageDigits = {
    1024 {1,2,3},
    2048 {4, 5, 6}
};
```

So my question is what is that data type in Python called and what is the best way to have a similar thing in c++?

Comment: Are you sending the object from python to C++ or are you just converting some code from python to C++?

Comment: you dont know what the python object really is, but you want the same in c++, why?

Comment: @NathanOliver yeah converting from py to cpp

Comment: When asking for help with code that does not compile, please include a [mcve] and the error message in the question

Comment: @user463035818 all I need is to for example say give me the 2nd element where the key is 1024.

Comment: Will all of the `[1,2,3,4]` parts have the same number of elements and will the number of elements need to grow or shrink?

Comment: the number of elements in the [...] parts are constant...but the keys can grow/shrink

Comment: The python code is a dictionary. For example ADIG[1024] = [1,2,3,4] [for more](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) and possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151480/simple-dictionary-in-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You almost got the syntax correct:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> G_Calib_VoltageDigits = {
    {1024, {1, 2, 3}},
    {2048, {4, 5, 6}}
};
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/qwkqNN)

Explanation: a `std::map` or a `std::unordered_map` contains elements as pair. A space cannot separate initializer arguments. The correct syntax require a set of braces for the pair, and another for the vector.