# Can you create a string based dictionary in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a python-like dictionary in C++, and using  was suggested many times but in my case i want to label my lists with words instead of "1, 2, 3, 4...", is that possible?

Example dict:
"Cookie": "sugar", "chocolate", "flour"
"Pie": "milk", "apples", "flour"

etc etc

Comment: Like `std::map<std::string>, std::vector<std::string>>`?

Comment: well I've tried `std::map<std::string, std::string>` but the problem is, then in my "cookie:" list, I can only include one value (for exmp: "sugar"), im currently trying to make it work with `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>` as it can store multiple values in one list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple dictionary in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151480/simple-dictionary-in-c)

Comment: I have given an example of using this, but I used `unordered_map` for better performance since the order of the indexes doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something really beautiful like this using the data structure proposed by @Retired Ninja. You can use `unordered_map` instead of `map` for better performance, since the order of the indexes doesn't matter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unordered_map<string, vector<string>> dict = {
        {"Cookies", {"sugar", "chocolate", "flour"}},
        {"Pies", {"milk", "apples", "flour"}},
        {"Drinks", {"Refrigerant", "Beer", "Juice"}},
        //And so on... You can add values later
    };
    
    for(const auto& object : dict){

        cout<<object.first<<": {";

        for(const auto& value : object.second){
            cout<<value<<", ";
        }

        cout<<object.first<<'}';
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```